# How to find out which picture was sent by the telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I need to compare the image from the computer with the image that my telegram bot sent.

I need to compare them in order to insert a link with a description for a certain picture

I'm trying:

```
if p4 == message.photo
```

but I can't do anything because message.photo = None. Which value exactly do I need to compare?

```
p4 = open("img/1 (1).jpg")
    time.sleep(1)
    if p4 == message.photo:
        print(10)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, p4)
```

print(10) - аcts as a link for now

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway.  `p4` is not an image, it's a file object.  You haven't even read the contents.  Surely there must be a better way of doing what you are doing.  Can't the bot send the text as well?

Comment: es, I understand that this is a file object and I did it out of desperation
There is too much text, so it's easier to link. In any case, I need to compare the images, because there are 50 such pictures and each picture has its own unique description

Comment: But why would you do this at the receiving end, instead of sending everything you need from the bot itself?  It's not very efficient to do a byte-for-byte comparison of 50  100k byte files every time you get a message.  It's not the sensible way to do this.